# Geo Coding Service not available

Tags: android, google-maps, reverse-geocoding

I am using **Emulator Google api's** (Google inc). i want to get the address of giver geopoint.
but i am getting this "*Service not available*" error. i am currently on api level 10. some one told me  about this bug on emulator. but i dont think it is on my emulator, because the built in map application is working fine .

Here is my code for getting location from points:

```
GeoPoint point = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                        (int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
                Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(GoogleMaps.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
                try {
                    List<Address> addresses = coder.getFromLocation(
                            point.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6,
                            point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);
                    String address = "";
                    Address a = addresses.get(0);
                    Toast.makeText(GoogleMaps.this, a.getCountryName(), 300)
                            .show();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Toast.makeText(GoogleMaps.this, e1.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

Comment: Did you try it on a real device? That would easily show whether it is an emulator bug.

Comment: "Because the built in map application is working fine" -> I understand your reasoning, but trust me, that doesn't really mean anything. I've experienced both at the same time. Try it on a real device, as Dan proposes.

Comment: try the same code in higher API level as I found  lot off  discussion about geo coding doesn't work in 2.3.

Comment: okay  i have android sdk tool 21.0 if i install android 3.0 will it be an issue ?

Answer (score 0):

u can try this one :

```
private String getAddress(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE){
        String strAdd = "";
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);

            if(addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");
                for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                }
                strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                MLog.v("My Current loction address", ""+strReturnedAddress.toString());
            }
            else{
                MLog.v("My Current loction address", "No Address returned!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            MLog.v("My Current loction address", "Canont get Address!");
        }
        return strAdd;
    }
```